# Pointer to an array only working inside main()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How come the following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int (*daytab)[13];
    int no_leap_year[13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30};
    daytab = &no_leap_year;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

while the following generates an error and a warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*daytab)[13];
int no_leap_year[13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30};
daytab = &no_leap_year;

int main()
{
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The error messages are as follows:

```
error C2040: 'daytab' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (*)[13]'
warning C4047: 'initializing' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (*)[13]'
```

I don't understand why having these declaration outside `main()` makes any difference. How does making `daytab` and `no_leap_year` local or external affect their data types?

Comment: This: `daytab = &no_leap_year;` is a statement, not a declaration.

Comment: The error message is unclear because the compiler, knowing that a statement cannot appear in that context, assumes that `daytab = &no_leap_year;` is a declaration, with the unspecified type defaulting to `int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This statement:

```
daytab = &no_leap_year;
```

(and all other statements) aren't allowed outside of a function context.  Some minor rearrangement will fix it for you:

```
int no_leap_year[13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30};
int (*daytab)[13] = &no_leap_year;
```

Comment: one thing i don't understand,i wrote the same statement as this : 'daytab=no_leap_year;' and it showed **warning**, why?, the name of any array represents the address of its first element and the '&' operator does the same,so why this warning.

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers.  There are hundreds of questions and answers on stack overflow to read more about the difference, or you can check out the comp.lang.c FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Carl Norum you can't write this statement:

```
daytab = &no_leap_year;
```

outside of a function just because this is an assignment operation you are performing and assignment operations aren't allowed outside `main()` or any other function,you will have to define the storage class for every datatype outside the function.